I have a Li-ion “battery container” and I need help identifying an IC
I have 2 of these battery containers.
They house 2 batteries each and have 1 PCB.
The IC I need help identifying is an SOT23-5 with
marking R3JR with an underscore under all the letters

the other PCB shows an IC with R3JY with underscore under it.

I’ve tried searching through a lot of websites with databases of IC markings but no luck.
I have also drawn a sketch of the PCB with no values of the components if needed.
Oh yeah and the component with a D inside is a diode whose polarity I cannot determine because both PCBs have it damaged.

Container

PCB


Reverse-engineering part of the schematic even if it's not polished is certainly a step above the typical "my tv is broken, what is this component???" question!

I could add a picture of what the container and the pcb and battery look like if it helps. Oh yeah i also forgot to mention that the batteries are Li-ion

It's a Ablic S-8211EAJ-M5T1U battery protection IC.

I can't find pictures of the part, but other Ablic parts in a SOT-23-5 package also use 4 characters with an underscore as marking, see for example the S-1200B50-M5T1U:

(Source: jlcpcb.com)

Oh cool I found it too lol thanks anyways

Oh yeah by the way where did you find the marking specifications?

@Noirher It's in the datasheet on page 21. I missed it at first.

I think I may have found 1 website which tells me what this IC may be.
https://www.qsl.net/d/dl7avf/charts/smdcode/cr.html#TOC
It tells me that I am looking at an IC with another code (S-8211EAJ-M5T1U)
I’ve read through the datasheet but I’m not convinced that it is the same though, cause in all my testing, I have observed that the top right pin is Not Connected, so what the datasheet seems to be implying should be that it is not the same IC.
Oh wait I’m stupid, I somehow missed the NC on the datasheet somehow
